# Matplotlib. TypeError: the dtypes of parameters y (<U26) and height (float64) are incompatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

При построении столбчатой диаграммы я столкнулся с ошибкой:

> TypeError: the dtypes of parameters y (<U26) and height (float64) are incompatible

Данные:

```
names_channel = ['T-Series', 'Cocomelon - Nursery Rhymes', 'SET India', '✿ Kids Diana Show', 
 'Zee Music Company', 'Like Nastya', 'Vlad and Niki', 'Zee TV', 'Movieclips', 'Sony SAB']

view = [118580091, 103596299, 82789893, 72493426, 31921080, 51551421, 54610393, 45986714, 34366356, 64350191]
```

**Код:**

```
plt.barh([names_channel], [view])
plt.show()
```

Как же мне исправить ошибку и построить столбчатую диаграмму?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names_channel = [
    'T-Series', 'Cocomelon - Nursery Rhymes', 'SET India', 
    '✿ Kids Diana Show', 'Zee Music Company', 'Like Nastya', 
    'Vlad and Niki', 'Zee TV', 'Movieclips', 'Sony SAB'
]

view = [
    118580091, 103596299, 82789893, 72493426, 31921080, 51551421, 
    54610393, 45986714, 34366356, 64350191
]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, sharey=True)
axes.barh(names_channel, view, align='center', color='b') 
axes.invert_xaxis()

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Кстати, вся проблема тут только в лишних квадратных скобках:

```
plt.barh([names_channel], [view])
         ^             ^  ^    ^
```

Если их убрать, всё рисуется, никаких лишних телодвижений не нужно:

```
plt.barh(names_channel, view)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]